# How to draw a finite line in Eyeshot 12

Tags: c#, eyeshot

I need to draw a line representing a z-axis from the origin up x units. I was able to create an xy plane by assigning one to Model.Grid.Plane. For context I will be building a point cloud to insert as an entity on the grid (already figured that out).

I tried to look at examples but they seem overcomplicated for my needs. Any info would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean?

```
Line ln = new Line(0,0,0, 0,0,x);

model1.Entities.Add(ln, Color.Blue);
```